# How to know when the Draft.js plugins are ready?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am using Draft.js plugin [Linkify](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/tree/master/draft-js-linkify-plugin).

I am trying to load the content from the local storage and then linkify it.

Now I have to use `setTimeout` to wait linkifyPlugin ready. If not, the content loaded will be pure text which is not linkified.

Is there any way like event I can use to know when plugin is ready?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // ...
    if (hasDraft) this.loadEditor(draftFromLocalStorage);
  }


  loadEditor = rawContent => {
    // here I have to use setTimeout to wait linkifyPlugin ready
    setTimeout(() => {
      const editorState = EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, convertFromRaw(rawContent));
      this.setState({ editorState });
    }, 5);
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        plugins={[linkifyPlugin]}
        onChange={this.onEditorChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Promise`

```
loadEditor(rawContent){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let editorState = EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, convertFromRaw(rawContent));
    resolve(editorState);
  });
}
//call it after component has mounted
componentDidMount(){
  this.loadEditor(draftFromLocalStorage).then(data => this.setState({ editorState: data }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but not help. The thing is I am waiting the plugin ready, not editorState ready.

Comment: without `setTimeout`, is `this.state.editorState === undefined` ?

Comment: `this.state.editorState` has value. My guess is the plugin is loaded after editor.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, looking at the source code there's no reason to think the plugin has async code: https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/tree/master/draft-js-linkify-plugin.

You could try putting a breakpoint on this function: https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/draft-js-linkify-plugin/src/linkStrategy.js

That function is called for every block in the state, so you should be able to see whether the text is processed by Linkify or not. If you remove the timeout and the function is still being called, then the problem should be somewhere else (because it would mean that you have a problem with the rendering, and not with the actual processing).